# How to get URL params in React by using useParams()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have implemented react-router-dom for routing purpose. I want to use `useParams()` in my component.

Here is My Code

```js
// routing

import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Mypage from '../components/Mypage/Loadable
<Switch>
<Route path="/ok/:id">
          <Mypage/>
        </Route>
<Switch>
```

MyPage.js

```js
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

let {id} = useParams();  // ===> This says  **Object(...) is not a function**

return ( <p> id : {id} </p>)
```

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) everything needs to be wrapped in a `<Router>` element. Your code doesn't have that element.

Comment: Can you share your "MyPage.js" complete code. As what you are sharing is not a React Function, and you can't use Hooks outside of them. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should consider checking documentation of React Router V6

Comment: yeah ! it seems that switch is removed from V6